# Getting an specific item out of another webpage

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I need PHP to import another HTML file and get a specific thing out of it. Somewhere on the imported page will be a line like this:

```
<video preload="auto" loop="loop" data-bindattr-3="3" src="https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/v/videos/03F598B7-40F8-4FD4-AB39-90AFC4FEDC4F-123-00000044D7291C03_1.0.6.mp4?versionId=sn7CV5wXJKJY_.CJcPHrsyLRDAtveQYw"></video>
```

I need PHP to find that line and get this in a variable:

```
  https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/v/videos/03F598B7-40F8-4FD4-AB39-90AFC4FEDC4F-123-00000044D7291C03_1.0.6.mp4
```

I already did a lot, I guess I'm close. But still, PHP is not able to get it for me. I think it's a small mistake, but I really can't find it after trying for a long time.

Here's my code (so far):

```
if ($check == "true") { //Okay, we've got a working URL here.

$file_string = file_get_contents($url); //Import le page
preg_match('<video preload="auto" loop="loop" data-bindattr-3="3" src="(.*?)"></video>si', $file_string, $keywords); //Find it...
$keywords_out = $keywords[1]; //..get it
$url = strtok($keywords_out , '?'); //Remove stuff after the '?'

}
```

Maybe you instantly see whats wrong here. If so, please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

[`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class would be the best choice

```
<?php
$html='<video preload="auto" loop="loop" data-bindattr-3="3" src="https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/v/videos/03F598B7-40F8-4FD4-AB39-90AFC4FEDC4F-123-00000044D7291C03_1.0.6.mp4?versionId=sn7CV5wXJKJY_.CJcPHrsyLRDAtveQYw"></video>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('video') as $tag) {
        $link= $tag->getAttribute('src');
   }
echo explode('?',$link)[0];
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/v/videos/03F598B7-40F8-4FD4-AB39-90AFC4FEDC4F-123-00000044D7291C03_1.0.6.mp4
```